# TFS to Git migration tool

Tags: windows-7, git, tfs

I use a windows 7 machine. I've to change networks to access the TFS system, which is our central source control system. However, it is being increasingly difficult for me to manage multiple versions of the codebase, and keep running tests on each of the versions.

### [Git-TF](http://gittf.codeplex.com/)

This is a utility that migrates code from TFS to git. But I've doubts about how it works. Nothing is clear from the docs.

1. Is it a self-hosted git server?
2. How does it manage changesets that are already there in TFS?
3. If its not a self-hosted server, how does it affect my workflow? Where would the `git push` really go?

Comment: As we do not counsel on "does software X fit my needs", but rather recommend software that does: may I suggest you [edit] and adjust your question accordingly, before other community members have it closed? That is, if you're interested in existing solutions for such a migration. If OTOH your goal indeed is to discuss Git-TF, this is the wrong place.

Comment: 1. No 2. How do you want them managed? 3. If you want to migrate and then throw away TFS, your workflow will become the Git workflow, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git-TF is a bridge between TFS version control and Git. It is a set of command line tools to allow you to synchronise between a local git repo and a TFS VC repo on a central server.

1. It is not a git server. It is a bridge between TFVC and Git
2. When you `git-tf clone` from TFS all changesets currently committed are recreated as commits inside the local git repo. i.e. the git repo is a full representation of the TFS VC repo but in git.
3. you use git as you normally would. then you `git-tf push` to the TFS server. This effectively sends the local changes in your git repo to TFS as a TFS changeset.

Comment: So when you do a `tf checkin` does the current git branch get checked-in? Or all git branches will get checked-in?

Comment: you don't do a `tf checkin` you do a `git-tf push` which simulates a checkin. effectively it's the same as a push to a git repo. the tool is abstracting TFS so that it looks like origin

Comment: okay, so does that push the current git branch only? As in check-in that branch to TFS?

Comment: With Git TF, I believe that you can only clone from a single branch. so the branch you cloned from would appear as "Master" in your local repo. you would need to merge any changes back to that branch before pushing to TFS. There is another tool "git-tfs" and this supports multiple branches.